# CakePHP model, unknown column in fieldlist

Tags: database, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I have this model file:

```
// Myfan.php
class Myfan extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Myfan';
    var $useTable = 'myfans';

    function getAll(){
        return $this->find('all');
    }

}
```

I try this query (which is simplified to isolate the problem) inside my controller class.

```
$Data=$this->Myfan->find('all',
            array(
                'limit' => 10
        ));
```

From MySQL I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]:
   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Myfan.name' in 'field list'
```

My table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myfans` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `screen_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `age` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=705314 ;
```

I removed `myapp_cake_model_default_mydatabase_myfans` file from `/httpdocs/app/tmp/cache/models` folder. Cake created file automatically but I still get the same error. How can I solve this?

I even don't have "name" field inside my table now. But I'm not sure whether I had before or not. Where does Cake checks for that field?

**Edit**: I get the same error when I change query to this:

```
$Data=$this->Myfan->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Myfan.screen_name' => $screenname),
        'order' => array('Myfan.id DESC')
    ));
```

Also my AppModel

```
// AppModel.php
App::uses('Model', 'Model');

class AppModel extends Model {
}
```

Comment: Is this the *actual* code of your model, or is there more code in it (validation rules, relations, virtual fields?)

Comment: @thaJeztah Yes that's actual code. No more relations etc.

Comment: Can you add the full query that produces the error to your question? (Please, use edit, not add it as a comment)

Comment: Also, have you checked your AppModel, is anything specified in there (e.g. Default sort order, or display field like others suggested)

Comment: @thaJeztah I added another query that gives same error. My AppModel is abstract. I edited question.

Comment: I'd suggest to a) remove *all files* from **app/tmp/cache/models** and **app/tmp/cache/persistent** b) set debug to '2' inside your app/Config/core.php and c) add the *SQL output* of the query that causes the error (it will be visible on the bottom of your page if you set debug to 2)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a different display field, you need to tell the model that, as well:

```
$this->displayField = 'screen_name';
```

For "name" and "title" cake is able to auto-detect.

Comment: +1 This is probably what's going wrong. Alternatively you can just set it to false if you don't need a display field

Comment: Now I tried to add field key to my model query and it works like this: ````$Data=$this->Myfan->find('all',
            array('fields'=> array('Myfan.screen_name'),
                'limit' => 10));````   But I need to fetch all fields. Is it possible?

Comment: Afaik displayField will only be used for find('list'), not for find('all'). If *no* displayField is explicitly set, no errors should occur (having a 'name' field in your table is *not* required)

Comment: then you must have something in your model to specifically query the name... because cake would not do that for you. also make sure you cleared the (model/persistent) cache - if you changed that field recently.